# Double to Decimal without rounding after 15 digits

Tags: c#, double, decimal, precision

When converting a "high" precision Double to a Decimal I lose precision with Convert.ToDecimal or casting to (Decimal) due to Rounding.

Example :

```
double d = -0.99999999999999956d;
decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal(d); // Result = -1
decimal result = (Decimal)(d); // Result = -1
```

The Decimal value returned by Convert.ToDecimal(double) contains a maximum of 15 significant digits. If the value parameter contains more than 15 significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest.

So I in order to keep my precision, I have to convert my double to a String and then call Convert.ToDecimal(String):

```
decimal result = System.Convert.ToDecimal(d.ToString("G20")); // Result = -0.99999999999999956d
```

This method is working but I would like to avoid using a String variable in order to convert a Double to Decimal without rounding after 15 digits?

Comment: Do you know in advance the range for `d`? I can offer some lightweight solutions in pseudocode (I'm not familiar enough with C# to write them in C#) if you know that `d` is in a range like [-2..2]

Comment: d will always be between [-1,1]

Comment: I'm assuming this is a `double` coming from somewhere else that you can't change? If it's declared as a decimal from the get-go (`decimal d = -0.99999999999999956m;`) it maintains that precision.

Comment: You're right Chris, I cannot change the double value because it's return by another method that I cannot change

Comment: The closest double to -0.99999999999999956 is -0.999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875, which a decimal type should be able to distinguish from -1.

Comment: If you try to convert the double to a decimal you will have a rounded value. Try my first example.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan This is speculation only on my part but I can completely imagine a programing language from Microsoft specifying that the conversion from `double` to the language's decimal type produces exactly 15 significant decimal digits and sets the rest to 0.

Comment: The [MSDN help for `Convert.ToDecimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a69w9ca0(v=vs.110).aspx) says "The Decimal value returned by this method contains a maximum of 15 significant digits. If the value parameter contains more than 15 significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest."

Comment: Have a look to the Remarks of this msdn page :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a69w9ca0.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to decompose `d` as the exact sum of n doubles, the last of which is small and contains all the trailing significant digits that you desire when converted to decimal, and the first (n-1) of which convert exactly to decimal.

For the source double `d` between -1.0 and 1.0:

```
    decimal t = 0M;
    bool b = d < 0;
    if (b) d = -d;
    if (d >= 0.5) { d -= 0.5; t = 0.5M; }
    if (d >= 0.25) { d -= 0.25; t += 0.25M; }
    if (d >= 0.125) { d -= 0.125; t += 0.125M; }
    if (d >= 0.0625) { d -= 0.0625; t += 0.0625M; }
    t += Convert.ToDecimal(d);
    if (b) t = -t;
```

[Test it on ideone.com.](http://ideone.com/MevINX)

Note that the operations `d -=` are exact, even if C# computes the binary floating-point operations at a higher precision than `double` (which it allows itself to do).

This is cheaper than a conversion from `double` to string, and provides a few additional digits of accuracy in the result (four bits of accuracy for the above four if-then-elses).

Remark: if C# did not allow itself to do floating-point computations at a higher precision, a good trick would have been to use Dekker splitting to split `d` into two values `d1` and `d2` that would convert each exactly to decimal. Alas, Dekker splitting only works with a strict interpretation of IEEE 754 multiplication and addition.

---

Another idea is to use C#'s version of [frexp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1xfschh.aspx) to obtain the significand `s` and exponent `e` of `d`, and to compute `(Decimal)((long) (s * 4503599627370496.0d)) * <however one computes 2^e in Decimal>`.

Comment: I have tried your code sample but I get -1. Can you reproduce it on your side?

Comment: @StevenMuhr Sorry, I don't have C# or even any platform where I could run .NET code, but I will try to play with ideone.com and come back with something that works.

Comment: @StevenMuhr Method1, result: 0.9999999999999996. You need to add handling for the sign of `d`. http://ideone.com/MevINX

Comment: Working well. 3x faster than using a String. But its not working for negative values

Comment: @StevenMuhr I suggest using this to convert the absolute value, and then negate the result if the input was negative.

Comment: @StevenMuhr I have added handling for negative values of `d`, but of us two, aren't you supposed to the C# programmer?

Comment: +1. As you say, my answer didn't work for other values in this range, so I've deleted it.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Yes, it is simpler if `d` is known to be close to -1 or 1. Hopefully the OP would have said if that was the case (and then your solution is faster and more accurate).

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches, one of which will work for values up below 2^63, and the other of which will work for values larger than 2^53.

Split smaller values into whole-number and fractional parts.  The whole-number part may be precisely cast to `long` and then `Decimal` [note that a direct cast to `Decimal` may not be precise!]  The fractional part may be precisely multiplied by 9007199254740992.0 (2^53), converted to `long` and then `Decimal`, and then divided by 9007199254740992.0m. Adding the result of that division to the whole-number part should yield a `Decimal` value which is within one least-significant-digit of being correct [it may not be precisely rounded, but will still be far better than the built-in conversions!]

For larger values, multiply by (1.0/281474976710656.0) (2^-48), take the whole-number part of that result, multiply it back by 281474976710656.0, and subtract it from the original result.  Convert the whole-number results from the division and the subtraction to `Decimal` (they should convert precisely), multiply the former by 281474976710656m, and add the latter.