# Format big double with .ToString("f")

Tags: c#, double, tostring

I am stucked with this, if you can help me I'd be thankfull
I have a problem converting a big double to string with `ToString("f")`

In my code, I have the element

```
double test = Convert.ToDouble(2023092619393694.000)
```

in the spy the value is good
if I use `test.ToString("f3")` the value return is "2023092619393690.000" (the 4 in end is missing)

to reproduce

```cs
Convert.ToDouble(2023092619393694.000).ToString( "F3",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: double is IEEE-754 binary64 and has only 53 bits of significand, which is ~15 decimal digits of precision. `2023092619393694` contains 16 decimal digits

Comment: [Why does `Convert.ToDecimal(Double)` round to 15 significant figures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20495306/995714), [Double to Decimal without rounding after 15 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24586969/995714)

Comment: You are on a pre Net Core 3 framework? Should work on versions after that. But @phuclv statement is still correct in newer frameworks it will just happen a bit less likely (not to say on larger doubles). [Details](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) Key sentence "The previous implementation had a bug where, for strings that contained more than 15 significant digits, it would actually fill in the remaining digits with zero, regardless of whether they appeared before or after the decimal point."